# How to do custom mapping using mongo connector with elasticsearch

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch

I wanna connect **mongodb** and **elasticsearch**. I used **mongo connector** to connect them. I followed instruction from below link to setup==>

http://vi3k6i5.blogspot.in/2014/12/using-elastic-search-with-mongodb.html

I am able to connect mongodb and elasticsearch. But by default mongo connector created indices in elasticsearch for all databases of mongodb.

I want to create only one index for my one database and I want to insert only selected field of documents. for example: in mongo shell==>

```
use hotels
db.restaurants.insert(
   {
      "address" : {
     "street" : "2 Avenue",
     "zipcode" : "10075",
     "building" : "1480",
     "coord" : [ -73.9557413, 40.7720266 ],
  },
  "borough" : "Manhattan",
  "cuisine" : "Italian",
  "grades" : [
     {
        "date" : ISODate("2014-10-01T00:00:00Z"),
        "grade" : "A",
        "score" : 11
     },
     {
        "date" : ISODate("2014-01-16T00:00:00Z"),
        "grade" : "B",
        "score" : 17
     }
  ],
  "name" : "Vella",
  "restaurant_id" : "41704620"
  }
)
```

This will create **database hotels** and **collection restaurants**. Now I want to create index and I want to put only **address field** in elasticsearch for that index.

Below are the steps what I tried but thats not working : 
First I start mongo connector like below :

```
Imomadmins-MacBook-Pro:~ jayant$ mongo-connector -m localhost:27017 -t       localhost:9200 -d elastic_doc_manager --oplog-ts oplogstatus.txt

Logging to mongo-connector.log.
```

Then from new shell tab, I made command like :

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/hotels.restaurants/'



curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/hotels.restaurants/string/_mapping" -    d'{
    "string": {
        "properties" : {
        "address" : {"type" : "string"}
         }
     }
 }'
```

But only index is created in elasticsearch named as **hotels.restaurants**. I can't see any document for index **hotels.restaurants**.

Please suggest me how to add document for **hotels.restaurants**

Answer (score 3):

Well I got an answer to my question, while starting mongo connector we can specify collection name and the list of fields we are interested in. Please check below command ==>

```
$ mongo-connector -m localhost:27017  -t localhost:9200 -d elastic_doc_manager --oplog-ts oplogstatus.txt --namespace-set hotels.restaurants --fields address,grades,name
```